# is it proper to store openssl public/private keys in a database?

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, php-openssl

I have been working on my own API for the first time and have gotten to the point where I need to add authentication to protect future users.

I have no problems generating new public/private keys, however I've never user openssl or ssl at all much in the past and require storage of these keys (I believe anyways).

I am hoping to store these keys in a simple MySQL database, what is the best approach to keep this data secure?

Here is what I am doing to generate the keys:

```
    $rsa = openssl_pkey_new(array(
        'private_key_bits'=>2048,
        'private_key_type'=>OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA
    ));
    openssl_pkey_export($rsa, $private);
    $details = openssl_pkey_get_details($rsa);
    $public = $details['key'];
    openssl_pkey_free($rsa);
```

Comment: I wouldn't imagine storing private keys in a db would be a good idea because any connections to the database would have access to the keys. Having said that, I am not an authority on the subject in any shape or form.

Comment: I've managed to find some really useful articles on this topic identifying that my original idea was skewed as to what I should be doing, however I am still looking for a set proper method to do ssl with pub/priv keys in PHP.